# Unordered_map insert with void (*)() as value is not working properly

Tags: c++, visual-c++, void-pointers, unordered-map

I am using this unordered map:

```
typedef unordered_map <char, void (*)()> Keymap;
Keymap keys;
```

and trying to fill it with:

```
void assign(char key, void (*value)())
{
    if (keys[key] == NULL)
        keys.insert(Keymap::value_type(key, value));
    else
        keys[key] = value;
}
```

the instruction:

```
keys.insert(Keymap::value_type(key, value));
```

inserts the char into the key but value isn't initialized (NULL), so I have a map with ('s', NULL) instead of ('s', function_pointer).

The instruction keys[key] = value; is working properly.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This expression:

```
keys[key] == NULL
```

And in particular, the subexpression:

```
keys[key]
```

Has the side effect of inserting a new key-value pair in the map where `key` is the key, and the corresponding value is value-initialized. This is how `operator []` for `std::unordered_map` is meant to work (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at)).

This expression, on the other hand:

```
keys.insert(Keymap::value_type(key, value));
```

Will *not* insert the specified key-value pair in the map if one pair is already present for that key (see, for instance, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert)), and that value was just inserted when doing:

```
if (keys[key] == NULL)
```

So indeed all you want to do here is just:

```
void assign(char key, void (*value)())
{
    keys[key] = value;
}
```